# Pandas equivalent of pyspark groupby, pivot, sum

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, group-by, pivot-table

I am trying to create an equivalent for pyspark `groupby` `pivot` and `sum` in this stackoverflow question [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537661/pivot-dataframe-in-pyspark)

I tired applying pivot after groupby on pandas dataframe but is not giving results as expected. Sample data:

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Score':[28,34,29,42],'Status': [1,0,1,0,1}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.groupby(['Name').pivot(index='Status')['Score'].sum()
```

Comment: See [DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) _e.g._ `new_df = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Status', values='Score', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`

Comment: @HenryEcker, what if one value in 'Name' column is blank?

Comment: You'll need to figure out what you want to do with the missing values. They'll be excluded because they can't be grouped. If you're looking to do something with them you'll need to replace the missing values with some value _e.g._ "other" or "missing" etc.